# Keyboard layout suddenly changed

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Yesterday I noticed that my keyboard layout was not working anymore. I use English intl with <kbd>altgr</kbd> dead keys, but now if I use <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> nothing happens. On my second keyboard "menu" key is recognized as <kbd>altgr</kbd> and <kbd>altgr</kbd> does nothing, also fn keys have changed to media keys...

I tried to change layout from keyboard settings and use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

but nothing happens.

I'm running on Xubuntu 18.04 and I'm thinking to reinstall the system, as now it is unusable.

I hope someone can help me, thank you

Comment: Update: i tried my xubuntu live USB and the problem persists